# What is the difference between mongoose validation and using express-validator

Tags: mongoose, express-validator

Based on my own knowledge, you can do almost every validation in mongoose schema that you can do with express-validator. So pls can I just use mongoose or there are situation that I will need to use express-validator  too even if I only create new documents

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed, you can do almost every validation in your mongoose schema like you can do using express-validator. Mongoose now supports validation on `update` as well, so you are good to go.

Let me point out two cases:

- If the validation logic is simple and small, there is no problem
  about mongoose validation. But in case of complex validation rules
  and multiple fields, then express-validator may be better choice.

  If the mongoose [built-in](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators) validators are not enough for your
  validation logic, you have to create [custom validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators). You will
  have to add much more lines of code, ending up with a too big
  mongoose model file.

  As far I am concerned, i want model js files as
  clean as possible. Express-validator, which is a wrapper for
  [validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) offers validators (e.g. isAlphanumeric, isEmail and
  much more) which can save you from a lot of lines of code. Thus you
  keep your validation logic in separated files, and have your code
  more clean and organised.
- **The other point is about the code execution flow**.
   
  Express-validator is a validation middleware. When you send a form through a post request, you can run the validation logic and in case of any error you return error messages to client, without reaching the controller or service code.

  Again, to my perspective is a bad practice to run controller or other service code (depending your architecture), with data send from client without being validated or sanitized. Using Express-validator, when code execution flow reaches the controller logic, that means the data you are going to insert to database, are well checked and sanitized.

  Without using any validation middleware, you have to run all the controller logic, and wait for possible validation error, only when flow reaches the mongoose save or update method. Imagine your controller includes a dozen service functions. Why run all this logic if it is to cancel it 
  due to invalid data?

In conclusion, both methods can satisfy your validation rules. In my opinion, go with Exspress-validator for cleaner and more organised code, as well as for better and more safe code execution flow.

Comment: Thank you for this clean answer

Comment: I have a question about your second point. Let's say, I did the express validation. Should I do all those validations in the model as well or not? Because if yes, the validation will be running in two places. If I am not wrong, we have to either initialize or set at least one rule like datatype in model.

Comment: If you choose to go with express-validator, you can omit complex custom validators inside the mongoose model, since it is more difficult to maintain the rules in both places. However you could use some built-in validators

Answer (score 0):

Using express-validator can provide more flexibility and independence in terms of choosing different databases in the future. In case you wanted to shifts from Mongo DB to any other database. It allows you to perform data validation and sanitization directly within your Express.js routes and handlers, without being tied to a specific database or ORM like Mongoose.